# Dijkstra algorithm not working even though passes the sample test cases

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

So I have followed Wikipedia's pseudocode for Dijkstra's algorithm as well as Brilliants. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode https://brilliant.org/wiki/dijkstras-short-path-finder/. Here is my code which doesn't work. Can anyone point in the flaw in my code?

```
# Uses python3

from queue import Queue

n, m = map(int, input().split())
adj = [[] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(m):
    u, v, w = map(int, input().split())
    adj[u-1].append([v, w])
    adj[v-1].append([u, w])

x, y = map(int, input().split())
x, y = x-1, y-1
q = [i for i in range(n, 0, -1)]
#visited = set()
# visited.add(x+1)
dist = [float('inf') for i in range(len(adj))]
dist[x] = 0
# print(adj[visiting])
while len(q) != 0:

    visiting = q.pop()-1
    for i in adj[visiting]:
        u, v = i
        dist[u-1] = dist[visiting]+v if dist[visiting] + \
            v < dist[u-1] else dist[u-1]
# print(dist)
if dist[y] != float('inf'):
    print(dist[y])
else:
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is not implementing Dijkstra's algorithm correctly. You are just iterating over all nodes in their input order and updating the distance to the neighbors based on the node's current distance. But that latter distance is not guaranteed to be the shortest distance, because you iterate some nodes before their "turn". Dijkstra's algorithm specifies a particular order of processing nodes, which is not necessarily the input order.

The main ingredient that is missing from your algorithm, is a priority queue. You did import from `Queue`, but never use it. Also, it lacks the marking of nodes as visited, a concept which you seemed to have implemented a bit, but which you commented out.

The outline of the algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) explains the use of this priority queue in the last step of each iteration:

> 6. Otherwise, select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, set it as the new "current node", and go back to step 3.

There is currently no mechanism in your code that selects the visited node with *smallest* distance. Instead it picks the next node based on the order in the input.

To correct your code, please consult the pseudo code that is available on that same Wikipedia page, and I would advise to go for the variant [with priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue).

In Python you can use `heapq` for performing the actions on the priority queue (`heappush`, `heappop`).